# what is the difference between cron and systemd ?

Tags: cron, systemd

what is the difference between `cron` and `systemd` ?
 Why we can't use use only one of this two?

Comment: What do you mean? The two have very little in common, of course you can use both [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd). It's just that systemd also offers cron-like functionality, that doesn't mean that they are incompatible.

Comment: And what makes you think that we cannot use only one of the two?  I have many systems that use only one of the two.  I even have systems that use neither of the two.  This question takes a falsehood as its premise; or is badly written and does not in fact say what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 7):

They are completely different things. `systemd` is an `init` system (replaces the old systemV `init`). It extends it in the following ways:

- It unifies the init, login and initscripts, so that different distributions no longer have each its own custom set of scripts to load daemons
- It tracks the services (daemons) so that it has control over them after they start, it can also hold on to the sockets for communitation and start them on demand
- init was ok on the older, more static setups, but with hotplugging, volatile connections, multiseat invariants, systemd is a bit more robust.
- It parallelizes the boot sequence by figuring out the dependencies and starting indepenent things in parallel.
- It knows and controls a lot about your system - init just started the specified scripts and login interface and then did almost nothing until the shutdown. This is one of the things that makes people sceptical - it feels bloated and harder to customize or debug. Anyway - it monitors the processes, tracks changes in the hardware, controls time, locale and power management, mounting of storage *and timers*. In this respect, you don't strictly need `cron` if you are using `systemd`. However, it doesn't work the other way around!

So... if you use `init`, then you need `cron` or something similar to schedule periodic tasks. If you use `systemd`, you can still use `cron`, but you can also rewrite the rules as `.timer` files and let `systemd` worry when to start things (instead of relying on a separate daemon).